# Proper way to connect to backend using React and RESTful Web Services

Tags: reactjs, json, ruby-on-rails, rest, webapi

I have a SPA application using reactJS for the front end, and Ruby on Rails for the backend; all navigation is routed through the react router. My question is, how do I access my model using react?

I think the proper way would be to expose the functionality of the model through a REST API. The problem is that the model's REST API is routed to return a page and not a JSON object. For example, /posts/index will return the posts index page, NOT the list of posts. What I need to do is to call another request when the user enters "/post/index", i.e., call a request from the index component, to retrieve the posts and return them as a JSON object. My workflow would be something like this: User navigates to index page > React sends HTTP request to access server.

One potential solution is maybe to implement a second controller, called say posts_react_controller, and then have this controller return JSON data and expose it via the appropriate url. Is this best practice?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're using a SPA you'll need an API of some sort (e.g. REST), which means you will probably need another controller for each model. Haven't used Rails in a while but I'll bet there's an easy way to add a REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails servers can be run in [API-only mode](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html), this is exactly what you need. You should be able to continue using your existing controllers and have them serve JSON instead of HTML.

Another option is to append a file type to your requests (`/post/index.json`), and modify your controller to handle [different request formats](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data):

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render xml: @users }
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end
end
```

With either route you'll probably want to use a gem like [`jbuilder`](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) which gives you a DSL for building JSON responses, similar to how you use ERB to generate HTML.